# Shiny download report cannot run examples locally

Tags: r, path, shiny, knitr

I want to create a shiny app that lets me download reports.  As such I have found two examples by Yihui.  [Example 1](https://gist.github.com/yihui/6091942), [Example 2](https://github.com/rstudio/shiny-examples/tree/master/016-knitr-pdf).

I can run the gist (example 1) by `shiny::runGist()` and it works fine.  I am able to download the example document.  When I copy the code and run the app from R Studio I receive the following error when I try to download the document:

```
 Running 'texi2dvi' on 'input.tex' failed.
    Messages:
    /usr/bin/texi2dvi: pdflatex exited with bad status, quitting.
    /usr/bin/texi2dvi: see input.log for errors.
```

I have researched this error and came upon [this](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/communities/public/questions/200659606-pdflatex-problem) link and it seems to be the same problem, although it remains unresolved.

I have gone through the suggestions and I believe it has something to do with my PATH, although this is a subject I am unfamiliar with and trying to understand.  Typing the command **$PATH** into terminal I receive the following:

-bash: **/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/usr/texbin**: No such file or directory

I also opened the app in my browser.  I received the following different error when trying to download the document from the browser:

```
.onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'tcltk', details:
call: system2("otool", c("-L", shQuote(DLL)), stdout = TRUE)
error: error in running command
```

I continue to receive this error when I try to run the app in R Studio and X11 now opens.

I receive the same error when I try to load the package tcltk package.

The example 2 I am able to run and download a document on my machine, but it is only partially compiled, and does not look like the document I download from the same app running on the shiny gallery [here](http://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/download-knitr-reports.html).

My document looks like

> Here is my regression model:
>
> options(digits = 4)  fit <- lm(regFormula(), data = mtcars)b <-
>   coef(fit)summary(fit)The fitting result is          *mpg = r b[1] + r
>   b[2]r input*x $. Below is a scatter plot with the regression line.
>
> par(mar = c(4, 4, 1, 1)) plot(regFormula(), data = mtcars, pch = 19,
>   col = 'gray')abline(fit, col = 'red', lwd = 2)

I am not sure if these problems are linked or separate.

I am hesitant to make changes to my PATH because it is unfamiliar to me, but if this is what I need to focus on please let me know. I appreciate any help and direction offered.

This is on mac OS X Lion version 10.7.5

Comment: Do you have MacTeX installed? Is it up to date?

Comment: I'd recommend you to try to compile an arbitrary R Markdown document to PDF first, e.g. `File -> New File -> R Markdown` in RStudio. If you see any errors there, please post them.

Comment: I am able to compile the LaTeX table example [here] (http://kbroman.org/knitr_knutshell/pages/latex.html), and I can knit to word, pdf, or html with the minimal R Markdown example with 'File -> New File -> R Markdown' in R Studio.  I have MacTex, updated it this morning and had the same results.  Also, sometimes when I run an app from R Studio then close the app, the Run App button does not reappear, but I am left with the Reload App, and I can no longer run apps even from command line. I must restart R Studio to try again. Also I am editing my response above about example 2.

Comment: I have solved the example 2 problem. This was a newbie problem.  I copied the code from Yihui's repository, but it did not have the code chunks unless I looked at it raw.  I added those and everything works fine, I will investigate the example 1 further to see where I am going wrong.  Thank you Yihui for editing my response, this is where I began to realize something was amiss.